# "Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version" exception thrown when trying to remove azure bot password

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, azure-bot-service

I registered a bot using Bot Channels Registration on Azure portal. I then generated a password for the bot. Now my requirement is to be able to update this password programmatically.

I tried removing the password using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/remove-azurermadappcredential?view=azurermps-6.12.0) powershell api and also using Azure Active Directory Graph API. In the both the approaches I get the same error

`Updates to converged applications are not allowed in this version`

Can anybody help me how converged applications are different from non-converged applications? And how can I resolve above error or use some alternative approach to update the password for my registered bot.

Comment: This needs more attention. I also need this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to do with PowerShell at this time (it's the version of the cmdlets that don't currently support the operation). I attempted to try to *just add* an additional password via PowerShell, and got the same exception.

```
$pass = convertto-securestring "MyNewPasswword" -asplaintext -force
New-AzureRmADAppCredential -Password $pass -ObjectId $myapp.ObjectId
```

You can add and remove passwords through a GUI by going here:
https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/

Regarding your question of "*Can anybody help me how converged applications are different from non-converged applications?* ", I'm not sure I can answer that question. You might start here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/

Comment: My requirement is to update the password programmatically. So using gui is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your new password {password} and pass --available-to-other-tenants

```
az ad app create --password {password} --available-to-other-tenants
```